# Re-running a jupyter notebook cell is faster than initial run of the cell

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a python file with the following code in it

```
#Start of Cell 1____________________________________________________________
import numpy as np
import time
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
from numpy.random import uniform

N = 4

X = [uniform(-1, 1, [N,N,N,N]) for _ in range(8)]
        
def parallel():
    Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(np.einsum)('pqrs,abcd,ijkl', X[i], X[i], X[i]) for i in range(8))
#End of Cell 1______________________________________________________________

    
#Start of Cell 2____________________________________________________________    
start = time.time()
parallel()
print(time.time() - start)
#End of Cell 2______________________________________________________________
```

When I run this code using command line, I consistently get a run-time of about 2.5 seconds. However, I also made a jupyter notebook with 2 cells containing identical code. The code contained in each cell is shown using comments above. When I run cell 2 of the Jupyter notebook for the first time, I get a run time of 2.5 seconds, as I do when running the script in command line. However, anytime I re-run cell 2, I always get 1.8 seconds rather consistently. So my question is: should it be expected that re-running a jupyter notebook cell is faster than running it the first time? This doesn't seem to always be the case, so are there specific instances of code that I should expect this behaviour? This speed-up when re-running a cell doesn't seem to happen if I use `time.sleep(1)` instead of the `np.einsum` call shown in the above code.

Comment: probably there exist resources that aren't getting released.  I suspect one such thing is the "jobs" for the parallel processing.  Those processes get created, but they don't die when the processing is thru, I think.

Comment: Another possibility is the import statements. Python loads a bunch of code the first time those import statements run. The second time the same import statement runs, it is much faster.